# Warning: file() [function.file]: Filename cannot be empty. Why?

Tags: php, email

When I am going to submit this (Warning: file() [function.file]: Filename cannot be empty) warning shows. How can I solve this problem. Please help I am new in php. Email has been sent but files doesn't attach. I want to sending mail with attach with raw php.

may code is look like this:

```
    $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
                    $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
                    $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

                    /* Start of headers */
                   $headers = "From: $fromName";

                  if (file($tmpName)) {
                  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
                 $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb');
                 $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName));
                 fclose($file);

                 /* a boundary string */
                $randomVal = md5(time());
                $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";

                /* Header for File Attachment */
                  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
                 $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
                 $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"";

             /* Multipart Boundary above message */
             $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
             "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
               $message . "\n\n";

             /* Encoding file data */
              $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

             /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
             $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
             "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
             " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" .
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
             $data . "\n\n" .
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";
}

 echo $message;
$sendmail = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers");

if($sendmail){
  echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
 }
else{
  echo "Error in Email sending";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (file($tmpName)) {`

You probably want `if (file_exists($tmpName)) {`?

Also make sure `$tmpName` is actually filled out.

Comment: Thank you BMC the warning is not show anymore but files are not attach with mail.